# How to create multiple Panda Dataframes in a loop that can be used outside the loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to scrape a sports betting website and display the results with Pandas. I want to have a separate dataframe for each game.  Each game is split into away team and home team. I have a list for each team. In this example I would want the 515 list and the 516 list to be in one df, and the 519 and 520 lists to be in a separate frame. I cant figure out how to print the df outside the loop.

```
A = 
     ['515', '6:00PM', 'Toronto', '-5.5 -110', '-5 -115']
     ['516', '6:00PM', 'Washington', '233 -110', '235.5 -114']
     ['531', '9:00PM', 'Milwaukee', '-4.5 -110', '-4.5 -109']
     ['532', '9:00PM', 'Phoenix', '226.5 -110', '228.5 -112']

for i in range(0, number_of_games):

    df.loc[counter] = ([A[j] for j in range(len(A))])
print(df)
```

Inside the loop my df looks great, but outside the loop it only returns the last value. I know its getting overwritten but I cant figure out how to prevent this.

OUTPUT INSIDE LOOP

```
 #    TIME        TEAM       OPEN     CURRENT
0  515  6:00PM     Toronto  -5.5 -110     -5 -115
1  516  6:00PM  Washington   233 -110  235.5 -114
     #    TIME     TEAM        OPEN    CURRENT
0  531  9:00PM  Milwaukee   -4.5 -110   -4.5 -109
1  532  9:00PM    Phoenix  226.5 -110  228.5 -112
```

OUTPUT OUTSIDE LOOP

```
   #    TIME       TEAM        OPEN     CURRENT
0  531  9:00PM  Milwaukee   -4.5 -110   -4.5 -109
1  532  9:00PM    Phoenix  226.5 -110  228.5 -112
```

I bet I've looked through 100 posts on here and still cant wrap my brain around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi user, welcome to SO.  It would be helpful if you updated the code so that someone who wants to help can run it to triage.  e.g. A =  pd.DataFrame.from_records( [ ... should be in a format that I can drop into jupyter and run.  number_of_games should be defined in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have your reasons for wanting individual dataframes but you need to create new dataframe names/variables during each iteration, otherwise every dataframe is called df.

I rewrote your input because as the commenter said, you have left out a bit of your code and/or descriptions.

I wrapped your lists in a new list and just iterated over them.

```
A = [['515', '6:00PM', 'Toronto', '-5.5 -110', '-5 -115'],
     ['516', '6:00PM', 'Washington', '233 -110', '235.5 -114'],
     ['531', '9:00PM', 'Milwaukee', '-4.5 -110', '-4.5 -109'],
     ['532', '9:00PM', 'Phoenix', '226.5 -110', '228.5 -112']]
    

chunk = 2
total_lists =  len(A)

num_games = int(total_lists / num_lists)
for i in range(num_games):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    homeaway = A[chunk*chunk*i+chunk]
    for g in homeaway:
        dft = pd.DataFrame(g).T
        df = pd.concat([df, dft])
    globals()['df_{}'.format(i)] = df

print(df_0)
print(df_1)
```

Outuput:

```
print(df_0)
print(df_1)
     0       1           2          3           4
0  515  6:00PM     Toronto  -5.5 -110     -5 -115
0  516  6:00PM  Washington   233 -110  235.5 -114
     0       1          2           3           4
0  531  9:00PM  Milwaukee   -4.5 -110   -4.5 -109
0  532  9:00PM    Phoenix  226.5 -110  228.5 -112
```

But you may be able to use globals in your code.
Maybe like this:

```
for i in range(0, number_of_games):
    df.loc[counter] = ([A[j] for j in range(len(A))])
    globals()['df_{}'.format(i)] = df.loc[counter]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What if I have a random amount of games. How would I print the df_x if I dont know how many games there will be?

Comment: in my example, you'll know. it's essentially num_games (which 1/2 of the total of home and  away lists). how do you calculate number_of_games? that's your total, correct? since range is zero based if you have 43 as number_of_games, then the last dataframe should be df_42

Comment: Yeah thats correct. I guess I was thinking more dynamically. Ultimately Id like to be able to run the function and it create as many data frames as necessary, then convert them to HTML to run on a webpage. If I dont use separate df for each game, I get one big list with 20 rows (10 games) and no separation between the games. Its one big mess.   I cant wrap my brain around how to do that. Thanks again for the help

Comment: why not just create a concatenated string of html tables instead of dataframes? you can add whatever html you want between them as you're creating the set of html tables. Or, and I don't know what it'll look like is add a row of blank strings to each subdf and maybe you get a less ugly webpage :)  Anyway, feel your pain, but you'll figure it out.